# haproxy PROXY protocol to mod_remoteip sometimes shows wrong IP address

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, haproxy

This is a very odd problem I noticed while checking Apache access logs. I have HAProxy in front of a bunch of containers. It inspects the incoming requests (Host header or SNI) and forwards the requests to the respective containers where Apache instances are running. I have `send-proxy-v2` for each listener. Inside the containers, `mod_remoteip` is running with `RemoteIPProxyProtocol On`.

This all works like a charm, except I noticed that some requests show the IP address of the bridge instead of the actual source IP address. Now I am wondering: how is this even possible??? In the HAProxy logs I can see the correct source address for each request (they originated externally), but inside the logs inside the containers show the address of the bridge.

I don't understand this at all. Is it possible that HAProxy sometimes "forgets" to send the PROXY protocol header? Is it possible for external clients to somehow circumvent the PROXY protocol? Any advice on how to debug this issue is greatly appreciated as I am completely clueless.

My setup runs on Ubuntu 18.04 using HAProxy 1.8.8 and Apache 2.4.54.

**Edit**: The `mod_remoteip` docs state:

> If enabled with the On flag, the upstream client must send the header every time it opens a connection or the connection will be aborted

So it must be the case that HAProxy send the header with the wrong IP address.

**Edit 2**: I analyzed the logs further and noticed that all requests with the wrong IP address resulted in a 400 Bad Request. I did some testing (sending corrupt headers) and it seems that somehow the address is not substituted by `mod_remoteip` (at least not for the purpose of logging) when Apache "terminates" those requests with a 400 response. So my previous conclusion was complete nonsense, HAProxy has nothing to do with it.

Anyway, I'm wondering: does this constitute a bug or is it just something I have to live with? Mostly, these requests apprear to come from bots (either malicious or automated security scanners). I would much like see the correct IP address in the logs, though.

Comment: "some requests show the IP address of the bridge instead of the actual source IP address" Which requests? Does a given request always behave the same way, or does the same request from the same client result in different behavior when made multiple times?

Comment: @larsks That's a good question. I don't know. Those requests come from the internet. I have no control over them. I have not been able to reproduce this behavior by sending my own requests. I will investigate the logs further and try to find a pattern